# Location allocation with a maximum occupancy and distance

Tags: pyqgis, iteration, location-allocation, qgis-modeler

I am working on a project where students can be assigned to multiple schools. I have the location assignment with the plugin QNEAT3 and the OD Matrix. In this was calculated from each school the path to each student. Now the schools have a maximum occupancy of, for example, 200 students (the occupancy can vary) and the school route must not be longer than 3 kilometers.
How can I achieve the maximum occupancy for each school with the students that are in the nearest vicinity but not further than 3 kilometers away?

I need a solution in the graphical modeler or with pyqgis. so that I can apply the solution to other schools.

I have tried different approaches in the graphical modeler but none gave the desired solution.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to feature the attempt that came closest to your goal,  We are a *problem-solving* site; we need a problem, not just a task.

Comment: You can use a Virtual Layer/SQL